# Formik useField() hook and components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik

I have a form with multiple pop-up menus. I'm using the `formik-material-ui` library for UI, and I've refactored the repetitive pop-ups into a component. When the component's code is in situ, in the form document, everything works as expected. However, if I refactor the component to a file, and import, something goes wrong, and Formik seems to 'lose touch' with the changing pop-up: the control draws as expected, and behaves as expected, but once selection is completed, the value is not saved to the pop-up, and the field appears empty. Here's the exported component:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState }  from 'react';
import UserContext from '../UserContext';
import { MenuItem, TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Field, useField } from 'formik';

export default function UserSelect (props) {
  const [ field, meta ] = useField(props);
  const [ users, setUsers ] = useState([]);
  const { user } = useContext(UserContext);
  const { department, role , label } = props;

  useEffect( () => {
    async function getData(department, role) {
      let res;

      try{
        res = await fetch(`http://localhost:4005/users/${department}/${role}`
          , {
            headers: new Headers({
              'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + user.token
            })
          }
          );
      } catch(err) {
        alert(err);
      }
      const { rows } = await res.json();
      setUsers(rows.map((userRole, index) => (
        { index:index, value: userRole.username, label: `${userRole.surname}, ${userRole.forename}` }
      )).sort((a,b)=>{return a.label > b.label}));
    }
    getData(department, role);
  }, [user, department, role]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Field
        {...field}
        {...props}
        placeholder={label}
        fullWidth
        select
        label={label}
        type="text"
        value=""
        variant="outlined"
        margin="normal"
        component={TextField}
        >
          {users.map(option => (
            <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
              {option.label}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
      </Field>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

I'm using it in the main file like this, looping over and array of `{title, department}` tuples:

```
{departments.map( ( department, index ) => (
  <Grid container spacing={1}>
    <Grid item sm={6}>
      <UserSelect
        name={'assignedReviewer_'+index}
        label={department.title+'  Reviewer'}
        department={department.department} role="reviewer"/>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
))}
```

As mentioned, this works *perfectly* when the component is inside the same file, but fails when imported. Am I supposed to be doing something with the `meta` props inside the component?

Comment: Have you tried loading the component with react.lazy and suspense?

Comment: Not sure what good that would do? I included the useEffect code because it actually works - I get a list of reviewers to select in a pop-up... but once selected, the selection isn't saved to the pop-up value. I will investigate.

Comment: I suggested it because it's possible that you're losing state when the component is unmounting.

Comment: As a second suggestion, could you test changing your props object destructure to: `const { name, department, role, label } = props;`

Comment: Sorry, this didn’t seem to make any difference

Comment: Well, it's likely the component is unmounting, or that the decision by `formik-material-ui` not to sync with external state is giving you trouble: https://github.com/stackworx/formik-material-ui/issues/76#issuecomment-499120026